# Why is there an ActionView::Template::Error when the image is there and precompiled?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deployed a change to a Ruby on Rails app on heroku (cedar) that included a new image.

UPDATE: I can reproduce the problem locally if I switch to production mode. The rest of what I said is accurate.

When I navigate to the page with an `image_tag` for that image, I receive the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (image_name.png  isn't precompiled)
```

Here's what I've done to diagnose/solve the issue so far:

- I ran `heroku run rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production` to ensure that the assets were precompiling without error. Everything looks fine.
- I also compiled assets locally and deployed with everything precompiled (which heroku noticed during deploy), but received the same error.
- Other images are fine.
- When I navigate to http://appname.com/assets/dir/image_name.png I can see the image fine.

What could it be? I'm interested in solving the problem, and in work arounds for now.

Comment: Can you check your `public/assets` folder in your Rails app, and see if image is there ?

Answer (score 0):

In `config/environments/production/rb`:

```
config.assets.compile = true
```

This shouldn't be necessary, but creates a fallback plan Rails thinks that an asset doesn't exist that does. It's unclear why the problem happened in the first place.